# How can I select a wallpaper that is not is the Pictures Folder?

Tags: desktop-background

I don't like to use the pre-made folders. I want  to organize the things the way I want and with the names I want. Moreover I don't want to have to move a picture every time I want to try and see how it looks as a background wallpaper. So, how can I quickly select an image in any folder as a desktop background.

Answer (score 11):

There are many ways to do so:

a) In **Appearence Settings** choose an image via the "+" button:

[image: appearence settings]

b) **Open an image** you like by doubleclick, rightclick and choose "Set as Desktop Background":

[image: eog]

c) **Shotwell** (photo manager) features this, too: Select an image and choose `File` → `Set as Desktop Background` or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>:

[image: shotwell]

d) With the **extension nautilus-wallpaper** you was able to set an image as background out of the file manager. But this [doesn't work since Ubuntu 11.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-wallpaper/+bug/875845).

As a workaround you can install [nautilus-actions](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nautilus-actions)[image: Install nautilus-actions]. Start it and add a new entry via `File` → `New action` or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. Name it "Set as Wallpaper":

[image: nautilus actions]

In the "Command" tab do following settings:

Label: Set as Wallpaper
Path: gsettings
Parameters: set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri %u

[image: nautilus actions]

In the `Mimetypes` tab edit the entry and change "*/*" to "image/*" (press <kbd>↵</kbd> to apply before switching the tab):

[image: nautilus actions]

In the `Environment` tab (press the arrow at the top right side to reach it) under `Appears if selection contains` change `Count: > (strictly greater than)` to `= (equal to)` and change the value to "1":

[image: nautilus actions]

Safe your edits by `File` → `Save` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Then open Preferences by `Edit` → `Preferences`. Uncheck "Create a root 'Nautilus-Actions' menu":

[image: uncheck preferences]

Close Nautilus Actions and restart Nautilus (file manager) by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and running `killall nautilus` or logging out and in again.

From now on you can set your preferred images as desktop background directly out of the file manager via rightclick:

[image: out of nautilus]

Comment: I recently came across a `libnautilus-gksu.so` file which is when put to `/usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/`, adds "Open as administrator" context menu entry (I know there's a package too available to install via Synaptic for this thing), is there any similar way for "Set as Wallpaper" option? instead of installing `nautilus-actions` which by default adds lot of context menu entries which I'll hardly use.

Comment: I'd be interested in it, too. Apart from that: If you follow this guide you won't have any other Nautilus Actions entries - unless you add them by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answers given, and also another simpler way that doesn't need the installation of any extra program or opening heavy programs, is the use of nautilus-scripts.
Specifically, open Gedit, and paste these:

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
path=${path%?}
quoted="file://$path"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "$quoted"
```

Next, save the file as 'Set as Background' under ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts.
To access the directory ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts you will need to go to your home directory through the save dialog of Gedit and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> so as to show the 'hidden' directories (the ones starting with a dot ".") and select the .gnome2 folder and next the nautilus-scripts folder.

Next, you have to make the saved file executable. You will need to open your home folder, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> so as to show the 'hidden' folders, navigate to .gnome2 and next to nautilus-scripts, right click on the saved file 'Set as Background', click on Properties, click on 'Allow executing file as program' and close the dialog.

---

Now, right-clicking on every file will result on this:

[image: right click and set as background]

Answer (score 1):

Click the + sign at the bottom left of the 4x4 wallpaper icon grid.

You can also place links in the main pictures folder, that take you elsewhere (drag a folder with middle button, instead of left, to create a link)

Answer (score 0):

You can also open picture in Image Viewer and then on the top of the screen select Image>Set As Desktop Background.

Answer (score 0):

My settings looks different than the screen shots in here, and I don't want to both making scripts for this. I discovered an easy way to do this using **Tweak Tool**.

Open **Tweak Tool** > **Desktop**.

Then you can select any image you want for either the lock screen or background and you can change the zoom mode (an option my background settings pane lacks).